# Is there a way to have information automatically exported to various excel workbooks including their respective sheets, from a single master excel

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I'm in a position where I have to put various repetitive data points into several excel docs and or specific sheets in a mess of a document. As of current there are upwards of 4 documents that all get the exact same information while some of it may be in a different order.

[The type of data Inputting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry2S2.png)

As shown above would basically be the "Master file" to get the job number.

From here we go to another excel that has the various customers (spread through different docs)

[Example of the alphabetized customer list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSUee.png)

[Whom then intern have their own sheets in the docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPBis.png)

[Which then to to a customer specific status document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf8mc.png)

I've been looking for a good way to streamline this process so I'm not having to input these data points 3-4 times every single time a new project comes up.

At this time the best solution I've been able to come up with and test involves manually inputting the data into the first and second excel docs, then from there using a function such as:

`='\\File Path\Foldername\AnotherNestedFolderHere\[CUSTOMER LOG B TO I.xls]SHEETNAME'!A1084`

Then just modifying the cell info at the end to pull from whatever cell I need at the time for the last two workbooks. Ive been looking all over to try to figure this out from Googling macros to Youtubing VBA but nothing gets close to what I'm trying to do to the best of my understanding.

Edit: I did a little more digging, had an idea with using chatgpt. Well Bings version of it to see about writing something and after about 5 attempts this looks close to what I'm going for but upon testing, it just fails and I'm not 100% sure as to why

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim targetFile As Variant
Dim targetSheet As Variant

'Open the source workbook
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook

'Ask user to select target workbook
targetFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")

'Open the target workbook
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(targetFile)

'Ask user which worksheet to put data onto
targetSheet = InputBox("Enter worksheet name:")

'Set the source worksheet
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Set the target worksheet
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(targetSheet)

'Find the last row in the source worksheet
lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy the data from column A to I on the last row to the target worksheet
wsSource.Range("A" & lastRow & ":I" & lastRow).Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

'Increment the next line in column A by one
wsSource.Cells(lastRow + 1, "A").Value = wsSource.Cells(lastRow, "A").Value + 1

'Save and close the target workbook without prompting for changes
wbTarget.Close True

End Sub
```

Edit: [New runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DpZj.png)

Comment: When you say "if fails"? What, precisely, do you mean? Possibilities could be (a) it fails to run (because of a syntax error) (b) it runs but hits a run time error (c) it runs but either does nothing or does something that you didn't want to happen. Rather than using a large language model, have you tried using Excel's macro recorder?

Comment: I apologize for not specifying what the "it fails" error entailed to correct that it says, "Subscript out of range". for the other half of that No I've not used the macro recorder fully in-depth I've made one macro a few months ago to try to make my job on a specific task a little easier but it wasn't a one size fits all solution. @DMM

Comment: Which line of code?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say, if it did I might be able to poke and prod see what tweaking may work or say something different, but that's really all I've got. though if i could take a guess at it (assuming i'm doing it correctly through the macros tab) `'Ask user which worksheet to put data onto
targetSheet = InputBox("Enter worksheet name:")`
right about there is when things mess up, after typing in what sheet I'm trying to have it target. I'm also fully aware that this may be a far more complicated way to try to reach the end result that I'm after.

Comment: When it fails go into the VB Editor. The line that is causing the error will be highlighted.

Comment: I just tried running it a different way via the VB editor (Just found the little play button) and it gave a runtime error this go around but I didn't notice a highlight. Will add a screenshot in the main bit for reference. I will say I've never done this before so I apologize if I may be misunderstanding something in regards to what you may be referring to.

Comment: @DMM - if you happen to still be following this I had some free time to do a little bit of messing about with the module ( I think that's what its called ) and found what you meant by the highlighted error `Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")` seems to be where the error is occurring. I've tried looking into it thinking maybe setting it to `Set wsSource = ThisWorksheet` but it also seems to throw the same error, after some googling I found something called `Me` but haven't delved into how that works. I may have an error somewhere else but cant pinpoint it.

Comment: The "Subscript out of range" error suggests that the workbook assigned to `wbSource` does not have a worksheet called "Sheet1". Check `wbSource.Name` by using a statement such as `MsgBox wbSource.Name` to determine if `wbSource` is actually the workbook you think it should be. Good luck.

Comment: I finally had a bit of time to do a look over of things and really give things a test once the new year turned over. I was able to get it to "work" finally but I've come across a new issue that I had not foreseen. At this time it will run through the script no errors so that's the good things, the downside is that it seems that once the new workbook is selected and it successfully opens, and pops open the box for user input for the sheet, it just copies the last line in the new target sheet into itself again instead of pulling from the original workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need VBA in order to make this workflow flow easier.
Excel within normal syntax is great at cell references, even at cell references  between workbooks. `Vlookup()` and `Index(Match())` are great examples of how Excel can look up specific information across wide ranges with little effort.

For an issue like this, where you simply don't want to keep entering the same information in, I think a simple cell `IF()` cell reference should do the trick.

Here's an example showing how you ordered your info:

[image: Here's an example showing how you ordered your info]

If you want to paste only the info from Client A, then follow a code like this:

[image: follow a code like this]

If it's hard to follow the code in the image, here it is:

`=IF('C:\Users\User\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G3="Client Name A",'C:\Users\zc222e\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!G3,"Not")`

Keep in mind, a "$" is used to lock down a code. without it, excel will shift the column and row as you paste the code into other cells, thats why I put a "$" in front of the G. we are basing whether or not it pastes the info on whether or not the client name matches our query. The other cell reference is open to change, because we don't only want to paste from that column.

If you have any questions or if I wasn't clear on something, please ask.

To answer your comment, in what does
"`=IF('C:\Users\User\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G3="Client Name A",'C:\Users\zc222e\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!G3,"Not")`" do.

```
=IF('C:\Users\User\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!$G3
'('File Path to folder to [File Name]Sheet.Name'! SpecificColumn then Row

="Client Name A",
' Checks whether the ref. cell contains a string that equals "Client Name A"
 
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!G3,
'If the check is true, pastes the referenced cell (not necessarily from the specific column

"Nothing")
'If the check is false, then pastes a string of your choosing, i.e. "Not", "Nothing", "Purple", "N/A", "", or etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will need some time to do some review and double check it as I only have access to test some of these files at work. Though through my current initial reading of your examples. that currently is what I'm attempting to do in a way though I feel I may not have explained things clear enough or provided decent enough screenshots. I've been told I have to be .. "careful" as to what information Im putting out there to get the assistance on.

Though i will say I'm not sure exactly what 

`'C:\Users\zc222e\Desktop\[StackOverflow -Master File-.xlsx]Sheet1'!G3,"Not")`

does

Comment: it might help to not read too much into the file name. think of it more like `IF([SourceFile.xlsx]Source_Sheet!Source.Column_Source.Row="Client Name A", then paste that info, else then paste "Whatever string you wanna paste instead")`     I was just using the file reference available to me between the workbooks I used to make the example

Comment: here is a link to youtube video that goes over how to reference data from a separate workbook. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdBnC1POxds all my answer adds, is an IF/THEN argument on whether or not to paste the data over. the youtube video also doesn't include some of the finer points on the reference. 1) if you have multiple files of a similar name, just in different folders, then including the file path will make sure you always reference the correct cell. 2) including the "$" before the column ensures that you won't reference other columns when copying the formula over to multiple columns

Comment: By what it seems based on your formula, and what has already attempted with the similar formula that I have been working with. It appears that the best rough course of action would be to utilize the reference lookup to eliminate 1-2 steps in the process as a whole. Potentially bringing my number of repetitive typings down to 2-3. I appreciate you taking the time to look into it, I was just unsure if there was a way to bring it down to a one stop shop having excel do the heavy lifting and spread the data across the other 3-4 workbooks, and in their correct sheets if applicable.

Comment: I do like the fact we both came to the reference lookup conclusion, the only thing I wouldn't be able to use really is that IF factor as I have a few hundred or customers across the other 3-4 documents that the "nothing" aspect of the string wouldn't need to be input anywhere. Though I'm not sure if the $ lockdown of a column would be something id need to worry about as we are cutting and moving things within the same excel to denote orders that have shipped versus what's still in house.

Comment: We're only locking the column down for the test query, if the query comes back as true, then the formula as i wrote it should paste for whatever column it's drawing the information from. if you don't lock down the query column, then when you paste it over multiple columns, then it will attempt to query those other columns.